# Multi stage relationship in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, mongodb, mongoose

I've 3 collections restaurants, menus, groups, items

Restaurant  -  Its the collection of restaurants

Menu        -  Its the collection of food menus
Group       - It's the collection of foods additional options like size, flavor, etc. It associates with Menu

Item        -  Its the collection of Items and it associate with group

Now I want to fetch A restaurant with its associate collection and documents

I've done this with Laravel Mysql now I want to achieve the same thing with Mongodb

```
    enter code 
{
   "data":{
      "id":20,
      "restaurant_id":1,
      "name":"Gralic Hot Pizza",
      "detail":"Item details",
      "regular_price":180,
      "discount_price":160,
      "category_id":2,
      "photo":null,
      "status":"active",
      "created_at":"2021-09-10T15:33:20.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-09-10T15:33:20.000000Z",
      "group":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "menu_id":20,
            "group_name":"Choose a variant",
            "group_type":"single",
            "created_at":"2021-09-10T15:35:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2021-09-10T15:35:02.000000Z",
            "item":[
               {
                  "id":3,
                  "group_id":3,
                  "item_name":"6 Inch",
                  "item_price":100,
                  "created_at":"2021-09-10T15:38:38.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2021-09-10T15:38:38.000000Z"
               },
               {
                  "id":4,
                  "group_id":3,
                  "item_name":"8 Inch",
                  "item_price":23,
                  "created_at":"2021-09-10T15:39:08.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2021-09-10T15:39:08.000000Z"
               },
               {
                  "id":5,
                  "group_id":3,
                  "item_name":"10 Inch",
                  "item_price":27,
                  "created_at":"2021-09-10T15:39:08.000000Z",
                 
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "menu_id":20,
            "group_name":"Size",
            "group_type":"single",
            "created_at":"2021-09-10T15:38:17.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2021-09-10T15:38:17.000000Z",
            "item":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use a MongoDB Aggregation query on multiple collections with related data, perform a 'join' using the `$lookup` stage.

Comment: please add sample data of each collection to make queery

Comment: How many layers of lookup can be done?
menus